# Docker container show "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Cli' not found in /bin/magento"

Tags: magento2, docker

I have installed docker for my local magento 2 development
Following this stuff https://github.com/redbox-digital/magento-docker
This currently best setup magento for linux container running docker. Hope team magento should port to linux soon
Back to my question

I can go to docker container and run

> composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition .

Yes i got all latest code version
But when i run php bin/magento i got not found Cli 

Could anyone tell me why it happens and how to fix it?

php -v show Cli 7.0.14 version

[image]

Comment: Is your Magento installation complete, can you run it from your browser?

Comment: No. I cant even run bin/magento. Got error descript above. Tried set permissions but not get any luck. It should be ok in order to setup install

Comment: Try Magento cli install: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-install.html

Comment: Try to use `/usr/local/php56/bin/php-cli bin/magento` instade of `php bin/magento`.